# How to find out which types implement which interface

Tags: go

Example:

In package `io` the type [`ByteReader`](http://golang.org/pkg/io/#ByteReader) defines an interface that wraps the method `ReadByte() (c byte, err error)`.

What is the easiest way to **find out** **which types** in the standard library (i.e. [listed here in golang.org/pkg](http://golang.org/pkg/)) **satisfy this interface**?

Is this just a matter of experience or is there any other help?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Mostly by experience. Anyway, for example:

```
jnml@fsc-r630:~/go/src/pkg$ egrep -nr '^func (.*) ReadByte\(' *
bufio/bufio.go:165:func (b *Reader) ReadByte() (c byte, err error) {
bytes/reader.go:59:func (r *Reader) ReadByte() (b byte, err error) {
bytes/buffer.go:289:func (b *Buffer) ReadByte() (c byte, err error) {
encoding/xml/xml_test.go:234:func (d *downCaser) ReadByte() (c byte, err error) {
strings/reader.go:58:func (r *Reader) ReadByte() (b byte, err error) {
jnml@fsc-r630:~/go/src/pkg$
```

And also the golang.org site has a [case sensitive search capability](http://golang.org/search?q=ReadByte).

Answer (score 11):

There are now better ways to do this than simply searching.

Go Oracle has an [implements query](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1SLk36YRjjMgKqe490mSRzOPYEDe0Y_WQNRv-EiFYUyw/view#heading=h.15us5y9rxrbh) that will show which types implement a particular interface, and which interfaces a particular type implements.

Additionally, here is a tool that claims to offer the same functionality: https://github.com/dominikh/implements.

**2020 Update**:  The official Go language server, [gopls](https://github.com/golang/tools/blob/master/gopls/README.md), also has support for this query:

```
    ➜ gopls implementation -h
    display selected identifier's implementation
    
    Usage: implementation [flags] <position>
    
    Example:
    
      $ # 1-indexed location (:line:column or :#offset) of the target identifier
      $ gopls implementation helper/helper.go:8:6
      $ gopls implementation helper/helper.go:#53
```

Comment: Go oracle was replaced by guru - https://docs.google.com/document/d/1_Y9xCEMj5S-7rv2ooHpZNH15JgRT5iM742gJkw5LtmQ/  and https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/tools/cmd/guru

Comment: If you know the package that holds the interfaces, e.g. in the `encoding` package, the pkg.go.dev website has an importedby tab that can be looked at (https://pkg.go.dev/encoding?tab=importedby) chances are high that you can find implementations there.

Answer (score 1):

Use the source code browser: https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/ .

When in the docs (e.g. https://pkg.go.dev/io#ByteReader ) click on the name of the type:

1. [image]

It will take you to the source code:

2. [image]

Now, click again on the method name, it will open the "References" deck on the bottom:

3. [image]

In my opinion it's not super convenient, but better than cli tools. This kind of information should be available straight from the docs!